# Как изменить MySQL запрос?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT user.name, DATE( office.created_at ) AS Date, office.id
FROM office, user
WHERE user.group_id =1
AND created_by = user.id
```

сейчас запрос выводит следущее

```
USER     | Date         | ID
---------+--------------+--------
юзер1     24.12.2012     1
юзер1     24.12.2012     2
юзер1     25.12.2012     3
юзер2     25.12.2012     4
юзер3     24.12.2012     5
```

Как изменить запрос чтоб даты не повторялись а вместо поля ID не значение, а их количество?

```
USER    | Date          | Count
--------+---------------+--------
юзер1     24.12.2012     2
юзер1     25.12.2012     1
юзер2     25.12.2012     1
юзер3     24.12.2012     1
```

Ответ:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS Cnt, user.name, DATE( office.created_at ) AS Date 
FROM office, user 
WHERE user.group_id =1 
AND created_by = user.id 
GROUP BY user.name, DATE( office.created_at ) 
ORDER BY user.name, DATE( office.created_at )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user.name, DATE( office.created_at ) AS Date, count(*) 
FROM office, user
WHERE user.group_id =1
AND created_by = user.id
GROUP BY office.created_at;
```